# syntax error : missing ',' before '<'

Tags: c++, syntax-error

error line 4
AND
 (line 53): see reference to class template instantiation 'ArrayStack' being compiled

```
#ifndef ARRAYSTACK
#define ARRAYSTACK
template <typename T>
class ArrayStack: public Stack<T>
{

private:
    T* data;
    int top;
    int size;
public:
    ArrayStack(){
         top = 0;
         data = new T[10];
         size = 10;
    }

    ~ArrayStack(){
        delete[] data;
    }
    void push(const T &t){
        if(top==size-1){
            T* data2 = new T[(size*size)];

            for(int i=0; i<size; size++){
                data2[i] = data[i];
            }
            *data = *data2;

            data[top+1] = t;
            size= size*size;
            top = top+1;
        }
        else{ data[top+1] = t; top = top+1;}

    }
    T pop() {
        if(this.isEmpty==true){
            throw std:: out_of_range " The stack is empty";
        }
        else{
            return data[top];
            top = top-1;
        }
    }
    T peek() const{
        return data[top];   
    }
     bool isEmpty(){
        if(top==0) return true;
        else return false;
    }

};

#endif
```

Not sure why this is giving me this error. New time C++ coder. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!
EDIT: Sorry! Forgot my Stack header

```
    #ifndef STACK
    #define STACK
    template <typename T>
    class Stack {
public:
    virtual ~Stack() {}
    virtual void push(const T &t) = 0;
    virtual T pop() = 0;
    virtual T peek() const = 0;
    virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;
    };
    #endif
```

Comment: Where is `Stack` definition defined ? Include that header.

Comment: I would guess you are using msvc and forgot to add a semicolon to the end of the definition of a class/struct/enum on another header file.

Comment: Where's the definition of `Stack<T>` live? You have no `#include`s for it, so that's going to be a problem. You also have problems with trying to `throw std::out_of_range " The stack is empty";` firstly because you don't include `stdexcept`, secondly because the syntax is wrong.

Comment: When showing us code, show us *all* the relevant code.  The error could very well be in a header (forget to close a class declaration?)

Comment: Thanks guys got it figured out. Forgot to include my stack.h Thanks yall

Comment: Also, is `throw std:: out_of_range " The stack is empty";` supposed to be `throw std::out_of_range("The stack is empty");` (also assuming you have `<stdexcept>`)?

Comment: Yeah, that should do it.  After I added `main()` at the bottom, I've received no further errors.